# Can I update a single source file on Heroku without recompiling the slug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm working on a rails project that's being hosted on Heroku. 
I'm wondering if it's possible to update one file, without restarting the app.

Why.  I have a bug, but I can't track it down.  It works perfectly on my local system, but it seems to stop mid way through processing on heroku.

As there are no break points, I'm scattering status updates in the code. (to be removed later)
But adding one line of code to a rails app is like a five minute process.

1. change file
2. stage file to git
3. commit file
4. push git  (all the above is quite fast)
5. wait for heroku to pull down the app, do what looks like a gem install, or at least a gem update.
6. change a few files to reflect the local url
7. start up the service again.

Is there a way to push the git without running all those other things?  Perhaps a special parameter to add to the push?

---

A further annoyance is that my git now has a bunch of check-ins that I don't want my co-workers to see.  I'm targeting a my own non-production instance of heroku (testing only) and there's no reason to include all these attempts in the global source control.

Comment: To debug the problem on heroku, try `heroku logs`. You can see everything that happens as you interact with your application.

Comment: The logs aren't doing it.. they don't give me enough info.. which is why I'm scattering status updates..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a good reason as to why it's not possible. When you push to Heroku, they produce a 'slug' of your application (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler). To provide the massive scalability that Heroku provides this slug is read only so that it can be spun up on multiple dynos which are likely to be distributed across many different physical machines. Each of these dynos runs a separate instance of your application whilst the routing mesh ensures that requests to your application goes to the correct dynos.

Now consider what would occur if any of these instances were writeable, if you're running 5 dynos you'd have your application running on 5 seperate instances - if a file is written how is it then distributed across of your running dynos? Yes, Heroku could have considered some kind of shared file system for running applications out of but that's complicated. By making the file system read only (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) this problem is alleviated.

If you've built an app and deployed to Heroku but forgotten to use S3 type peristant storage your application will let you upload files to it (via Paperclip of such like in the Ruby world) but that uploaded asset will only exist on the dyno that received it and will then be lost when new code is deployed or the application restarted as the dyno receives the latest code from the slug.

If you're debugging against Heroku don't forget you've got the usual git arsenal available, `git commit --amend`. Alternatively work in a branch and deploy that to directly to Heroku (`git push heroku <yourbranchname>:master`) then when you've isolated the problem rebase (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) your branch onto master squashing any commits you no longer need.

Comment: Now this is the best answer I've read. It makes perfect sense.  And it sucks.  The reason sucking isn't a reason not to vote up your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### XY Problem

This is a classic [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). X is your non-working code; Y is your search for a non-existent Git misfeature.

#### How Git Works

Git commits fundamentally work at the tree level, not the file level. As a gross over-simplification, a commit points to a tree, which points to a set of files. When you push a commit, you have to push all the objects related to that commit unless the objects already exist on the receiver.

#### How Heroku Works

Heroku [compiles the application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#compilation) in your Git repository into a slug. While you can [ignore certain files](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring_files_with_) during compilation, you can't avoid compiling the slug. That's just the way the platform works.

This is not a problem if you have a reasonable slug size; my Heroku apps only take a couple of seconds to compile. If your slugs are very large, and therefore take a long time to compile (you claim it takes you 5+ minutes), then you have another XY problem on your hands if you're trying to solve for "don't compile."

#### Debugging on Heroku

Heroku has lots of features and add-ons to aid debugging. Here's a short list to get you started.

- [interactive console sessions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/console#interactive_console_sessions)
- [logging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)
- [Exceptional Add-On](https://addons.heroku.com/exceptional)

#### See Also

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral_filesystem

Comment: Well five min is a bit of an overestimate.  It's actually just over 3 minutes.  Just long enough for me to open gmail.  <br> I don't think I have a huge app. 50 models.  Oh.. I solved for X, well before I posted the question. X was just a bug.. I wanted to solve for 3 min and I am indeed groping.

Comment: I also never cited git as having a miss-feature. I know exactly how (and love how) git works. My issue was not with git.  It was with heroku compiling, when rails is (according to every book I've read) not a compiled language and easy to adjust. 3 minutes from code change to run does not seem in-line. But I digress.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. The way heroku is setup, every time you push up a change the server will restart.

Comment: That seems... well wrong, and anti rails.  Isn't one of the huge selling points of ruby that you can change things quickly and no need to re-compile.  How is shutting down, and reloading everything then restarting, not a re-compile? Surely there should be a way.  I will find a way, else make one.

Comment: What if we got our rails app to save files in app directories? Overwrite code with new code files.

Comment: It only sounds "anti rails" because you're not understanding the whole system. There are very valid reasons why it's not possible and I can tell you right now IT IS NOT POSSIBLE. Your website on heroku is read-only and that is outside of your control. Rather than fight this impossible to resolve issue and getting side tracked you should focus on solving your original problem. My 2 cents

Comment: What is one valid (rails) reason to run bundle install after changing a  model? Even if it's only partially valid, I can't think of one.

Comment: It's not about "rails" reasons because what we're talking about here isn't the rails framework, it's the **hosting** environment. If you host the site on your own servers then yes, you can change a model and not run bundle afterwards. But you're hosting on Heroku and they have very good reasons for having a read-only file system.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can.

First, list all the files that have been modified since the last commit.

`git status`

Add the files you want to commit individually.

`git add location/file_name.rb`
`git add location/file_name2.rb`
...

Make commit to the files you added to push.

`git commit -m "committing files one at a time or two at a time"`

Now push

`git push heroku`

Comment: Hey mate.. I think you miss-understood the question. Not how to add one file to the git.. How to add one file to heroku. Since I only changed one file, I can stage/commit all. The push to heroku is the bit that needs to be optimized.

Comment: correct a typo.. push... go to get a cup-a, come back and repeat. Uggh.  --- Oh after a few of these go pee.

Comment: I think I understand what you want now. Unfortunately what you want is not possible. Once Heroku receives the push, it will install bundle automatically, and you can't control how the bundle is installed.

Comment: Not a big fan of that term "not possible".  I suppose I could do sit-ups during my RAD "compile" :)